# Conda environment cannot be activated anymore

Tags: python, anaconda, miniconda

I created a virtual environment using Pycharm for a specific project. Everything went well, activated it, installed packages and kept working. However, when I tried activating the virtual environment, it keeps giving me the following error:

```
    EnvironmentLocationNotFound: Not a conda environment: C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\project\venv_310

Invoke-Expression : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is an empty string.
At C:\Users\User\miniconda3\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1:107 char:36
+         Invoke-Expression -Command $activateCommand;
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Invo
   keExpressionCommand
```

Furthermore, the virtual environment doesn't show up when I do conda env list. I tried `conda config --append envs_dirs /path/to/directory/with/venv` however, I still don't see the virtual environment.

Comment: Did you create a *Conda* virtual environment? There are other types (e.g., `virtualenv`).

Comment: @merv it was a conda environment

Comment: Did you check the "make available to other projects" box?

Comment: @merv Yes sir. It worked fine until I deactivated the environment. Tried to start it up again was the problem.